# How to Customize Woocommece Checkout Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce with Wordpress.
On the checkout page, i want to remove all the fields (marked in red) so there is minimal distraction.
Can anyone suggest the code to do that?

[image]

Comment: the first message is about the product which you have added into the cart. You can remove it using hooks. i.e. https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-remove-product-successfully-added-cart-message/ 
Enable guest checkout to avoid that register and login message, and at the end, you can disable coupons from the backend settings of WooCommerce.

Comment: The PHP snippet worked. Thanks:)

Comment: Can you also suggest how to remove the header and footer from checkout page?

Comment: You can use the condition of `is_checkout()` this function will let whether this page is checkout or not. ie. if(!is_checkout()){ echo "Your Header Code"; }

Answer (score 0):

First make child from theme and you can customize in this

> woocommerce --> checkout --> form-checkout.php

by add filter in `functions.php` you can remove message

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
```

and by CSS you can make display none for div or class, but is very use full for shopping website.